# something wrong with my "rock, paper,scissors" code

Tags: python, python-3.x

Hey guys I have written the code below and everything seems to work fine except for when it is supposed to be a draw I keep getting "name2 wins" as well as when the answer is supposed to be invalid. I have no idea what is wrong as my logic seems correct.

```
print("Welcome to Rock, Paper, Scissors!")
print("Let's Begin ...")
name1 = input("Player 1: What's your name?")
name2 = input("Player 2: What's your name?")

print("Hello " + name1 + " and " + name2)
print(name2 + ": Close your eyes!")

choice1 = input(name1 + ": enter 'r' for rock, 'p' for paper, and 's' for Scissors: ")

print("Great choice! Now - cover your answer and ask " + name2 + " to choose. \n\n\n")
choice2 = input(name2 + ": enter 'r' for rock, 'p' for paper, and 's' for scissors: ")

if(choice1 == "r" , choice2 == "p"):
  print(name2 + " wins!")
elif(choice1 == "r" , choice2 == "s"):
  print(name1 + " wins!")
elif(choice1 == "r" , choice2 == "r"):
  print("It is a draw")
elif(choice2 == "r" , choice1 == "p"):
  print(name1 + " wins!")
elif(choice2 == "r" , choice1 == "s"):
  print(name2 + " wins!")
elif(choice1 == "p" , choice2 == "s"):
  print(name2 + " wins!")
elif(choice1 == "p" , choice2 == "p"):
  print("It is a draw!")
elif(choice2 == "p" , choice1 == "s"):
  print(name1 + " wins!")
elif(choice1 == "s" , choice2 == "s"):
  print("It is a draw!")
else:
  print("Invalid asnwer")


print("Thanks for playing Rock, Paper, scissors")
```

Comment: Where did your idea to put a comma in your if statements come from?

Comment: The logic is correct and so is the syntax... At least correct snough not to cause an error by the interpreter. You may want to relook the commas in your if statements, they seen to cause a compilation error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your entire method for checking multiple conditions is incorrect -

```
if(choice1 == "r" , choice2 == "p"):
```

takes the truthiness of the tuple formed by `choice1 == "r", choice2 == "p"`, which will be truthy always as it shall not be empty, so you'll never even reach the `elif` statements and player 2 will always win.

The correct way to check both conditions is with the `and` operator, and the parentheses are not necessary.

```
if choice == "r" and choice2 == "p":
```

Fixing all of these conditions should help.

Answer (score 0):

Change the ',' in all if conditionals for an 'and', like this:

```
if choice1 == "r" and choice2 == "p":
  print(name2 + " wins!")
```

Note: the parenthesis aren't necessaries.

Why always are you getting "name2 wins"?

Because of the comma, you where creating a [tuple](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/stdtypes.html#typesseq-tuple), wich is evaluate as true if isn't empty.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it

```
     choice = [choice1, choice2]
     if(choice == ['r', 'p']):
        print(name2 + " wins! ")
     elif(choice == ['r', 'p']):
        print(name1 + " wins!")
     elif(choice == ['r', 'r']):
        print("It is a draw")
     elif(choice == ['p', 'r']):
        print(name1 + " wins!")
```